# "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController::edit(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Tags: laravel

can anybody help me with this error?
Here my complete route

```
Route::resource('/blog/post', 'Backend\BlogController');
```

this is my edit function on BlogController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view("backend.blog.edit", compact('post'));
}
```

and this my button

```
<a href="{{ route('post.edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Try `action('Backend\BlogController@edit', ['id' => $post->id])`

Comment: Can you check if `$post->id` is not null?

Comment: do `php artisan route:list` in your terminal and share the log

Comment: Try to pass the whole $post object at your button route method

Comment: GET|HEAD  | blog/post/{post}/edit  | post.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BlogController@edit

Comment: i can't check $post->id,because has the same error

Comment: @KhairunNasyrah That sounds like `$post` is null. Does a non-deleted post exist in the database with the matching ID?

Comment: the ID exist in database

Comment: have you try to var_dump the id to check whether you got the id or you just getting null value?

Answer (score 1):

While generating a button, a correct way, according to the documentation is:

```
<a href="{{ route('post.edit', ['id' => $post->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

Note passing an array of options as a second argument.

Comment: @KhairunNasyrah Does `$post->id` exist?

Comment: exist in the database

Comment: With a `null` `deleted_at` column?

Comment: it has no delete_at